# how can i use alertbox concept of javascript in ant script

Tags: javascript, ant

i m using like following for generating alertbox in ant script.

```
<target name="javascript">
        <script language="javascript">
<![CDATA[   
importPackage(java.lang);           
alert("I am alert menu!");
</script>           
]]>        
</target>
```

but it's not working. showing following error

> javax.script.ScriptException:
>   sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "alert"
>   is not defined. (#4) in  at line
>   number 4

pls anyone help me out.

Comment: Any reasons' for using the alertbox? Including something that needs user interaction into the build script makes it unusable for any automatic deployments/coninuous integration scenario

Comment: yes for confirmation of build successfull msg displaying purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html), then you can do something like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
<![CDATA[
    importPackage(javax.swing);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( 'Title', 'I am alert menu!' );
]]>
</script>
```

*Based on [this source](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/).*

*edit*

I can't quite see what is causing the error in your sample, but the below works for me.  Note that you can't use `null` for the first argument to the JOptionPane dialog - the compiler can't disambiguate the two two-arg constructors if you try that.

```
<target name="speed">
<script language="javascript">
<![CDATA[
    importPackage(javax.swing);
    var optionPane = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( 'Speed in miles per hour?', '10' );
    var mph = parseFloat(optionPane);
    var kph = 1.621 * mph;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, 'KPH = ' + kph );
]]>
</script>
</target>
```

I get a modal input dialog "Input" with label "Speed in miles per hour?" and initial value "10".  Then this response:

[image: Image saying KPH = 16.21]

Comment: <target name="speed">
<script language="javascript">
<![CDATA[
 importPackage(javax.swing.*);
 importPackage(javax.swing.JOptionPane);
 var optionPane = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 'Speed in miles per hour?');
   double mph = Double.parseDouble(optionPane);
   double kph = 1.621 * mph;
 var optionPane = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 'KPH = ' + kph);
]]>
</script>
</target>

Comment: i  using above target for input dialog box but it's showing the following error`The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.`

Comment: pls suggest me how can i do it

Comment: `<script language="javascript">
<![CDATA[
    importPackage(javax.swing);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( 'Title', '`I am alert menu!`' );
]]>
</script>`
at the place of message content, can we pass the ant variable value bcoz i want to print sql select output content as a message in message box.
pls suggest me how can i do it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: i got it here i have to pass the variable name directly not like ${patch_name}

Comment: I get an `importPackage is not defined in <eval>.` error.

Answer (score 0):

To display a message you can use ants "exec" - to execute a shell command.
On Linux that command would be "zenity", see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity

On Windows ... well you can install zenity for windows: http://www.placella.com/software/zenity/

Comment: P.S. You can use the "resultproperty" of "exec" to get users input from zenity. See: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html